# NetBeans code completion shows the old names of classes that were renamed

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

In NetBeans 6.7.1, I had a Java project in which I renamed some classes. After renaming them, the code completion showed the old names of the classes and not the new names. When I would build a project that depended on this project, I noticed it would even create the .class files for the old classes. If I deleted the renamed classes and created them from scratch, the issue persisted. I could find no references to the old names of the classes in my project folder using grep. I would also get runtime errors where I had code using the new class names. When I would build the project though, it was successful. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying many different things, deleting my NetBeans cache folder and restarting NetBeans was the only remedy for the problem. On Windows, the cache folder is located at C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\.netbeans\6.7\var\cache. This seems to be a bug in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to still exist in 7.1, same problem with old .class files and removing the cache folder fixed it